# Seeking classified image download for soil,vegetation or water resources

Tags: data, india

Is there any site which provide classified image download for soil,vegetation or water resources?

It is particularly for Indian states, that I need them.

The raster data may also work for me in above aspects.

Answer (score 1):

For soils you might take a look at the [Harmonized World Soil Database](http://www.iiasa.ac.at/Research/LUC/External-World-soil-database/HTML/) (1km pixel size), and for vegetation you might be able to use the [MODIS land cover product](https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/products/modis_products_table/land_cover/yearly_l3_global_500_m/mcd12q1) (500m pixel size). I would recommend the ESA's Globcover product for vegetation (300m), but their [site](http://ionia1.esrin.esa.int/) seems to be under maintenance.

As for water resources, I'm not familiar with any raster products for India.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you that you want satellite data that can be used for classification.

Have you looked at the LISS-III & AWIFS data that is available from Bhuvan? This data can be downloaded at http://bhuvan-noeda.nrsc.gov.in/download/download/download.php

If this isn't what you are looking for, please clarify your question. I know quite a lot of NRSC websites inside out, and might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

The rasters for India (all states) are available here:
https://bhuvan-app3.nrsc.gov.in/data/download/index.php?c=s&s=C1&p=cdv2r1#

- This is a product of ISRO.
- A maximum of 20 bounding box rasters could be downloaded in a day per email ID.(as of today)
- There is no bulk download option.
- The rasters seem pretty HD
- Has the entire country covered

Putting this here in case someone from future needs this